# Server 2003 SBS DNS not resolving webpages

Tags: windows-sbs-2003

We have an SBS 2003 Server that has developed what I believe is a DNS fault. It is a domain server used for DNS, DHCP, file server and exchange duties. About 24hrs ago it became apparent that any internal clients, also external clients connecting via VPN were not able to display web pages. It was also noticed that the server itself was unable to display web pages. The unusual thing is that a number of services are still working such as Skype, Exchange is still sending/receiving emails for both internal and external clients, RDP and file access. So the only thing that doesn't seem to be working is displaying web pages.

The steps already taken in an attempt to resolve this are Winsock repair, checked Forward lookup, replaced router. None with success.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So DNS resolution is *working* or not?

Comment: Are you just randomly trying stuff or are you taking a methodical approach? It sounds like you're just trying random stuff. Start with one component at a time. When the problem occurs try using nslookup to check DNS resolution for the domain name in question, then report your findings back here.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to exclude the DNS problem, try acessing a webpage by IP address.
Example: instead of msn.com, try 23.101.196.141.
Also, you can check that with ping command; ping hostname and then IP address of a known site. If IP responds and hostname does not, it's clearly a DNS problem. If the IP does not respond or you cannot access the webpage via IP, then you have a http/https blocking problem.